# Lowest pixel resolution needed to support Chinese?

Tags: simplified-characters, writing, fonts

We are creating a product which has an small embedded OLED display (64 x 48 pixels). We would love to support Chinese in this product and wonder what is that smallest resolution that would be needed to support Chinese writing?

I assume simplified Chinese would give the best result?

Currently in our product, which supports English only, our smallest font size is 5 x 7. I'm pretty sure Chinese symbols will need more resolution.

Comment: It seems for recognizable Chinese characters, the resolution should be no lower than 7*7. I'm using my phone so I can't go check, you may download the fonts mentioned in this [page](http://www.zhihu.com/question/19704618).

Comment: I think 16 * 16 is needed as least. http://hefuliang.cai.swufe.edu.cn/EXAMPLE/PROG0069.htm

Comment: @Stan - I don't believe 7x7 is correct as counting the lines in some of those symbols its more... around 12.

Comment: @songyuanyao - Where do you get 16x16 from? I guess you are counting the pixels in the example on the link you supplied? The edge pixels are not used and again its looking like 12x12 might be sufficent!

Comment: @TheGrovesy Not only that page, I also searched some other pages by baidu.com, it seems 16*16 is used in many cases, and 8*8 is not sufficient. And according to [here](http://blog.codingnow.com/2006/01/windows_hz_fonts.html), 10*10 seems to be the limit.

Comment: I just did a search for 'nintendo gameboy chinese symbols' and found this interesting link: [link](http://www.mqp.com/fun/gb_chi.htm). It suggests that 16x16 is normal but it can be achieved using 11x11 or 12x12.
@songyuanyao - I have just seen your reply. Unfortunately my company has blocked that weblink! but it looks like I am close to an answer. I will check out that link at home. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @TheGrovesy there are a few **actual fonts with 8x8 pixels** in the link of my first comment, and I did see some samples before. I describe them as "recognizable", because it may be the limit to native speakers (with context). For 12x12, that can render a character rather clearly.

Comment: How did things go? You are welcome to consider posting an answer to [Drawing multilingual text using PIL and saving as 1-bit and 8-bit bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545359/3904031).

Comment: Related: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/142419693 https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/338579385

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## 8x8: Lowest necessary resolution for Chinese characters

As far as I know, the **recognizable lowest resolution** for Chinese characters, is about `8x8` pixels. The following paragraphs are rendered by the ***Special SimSun*** font's smallest 8x8 bitmap glyphs (Note: "*Before Revision*" is rendered by the Windows Vista's default `simsun.ttc`; "*After Revision*" shows how Special Simsun improves the quality). I believe native speakers are able to read these 8x8 resolution characters within the context, though a few are difficult to be recognized individually.

[image: Special SimSun]

> "The **Special SimSun** font is revised based on `simsun.ttc` and `mingliu.ttc` contained in Windows Vista: First, it replaces ugly bitmap glyphs of Windows Vista's `simsun.ttc` with those of Windows XP's, and adds a few other bitmap glyphs; Second, it completes the bitmap glyphs in CJK EXT A (6852 characters), and supports the GB18030 character set (27533 characters) – especially, some low-resolution bitmap glyphs are included so that characters can be rendered in the bitmap way under 6pt–21pt for 96dpi; Finally, all bitmap glyphs are revised one by one, so the rendering quality is improved." — By the author of this font

It would be remiss of me not to mention the `7x7` resolution font: `超宋体` (**Super Song**) made by [夏夏@bbs.themex.net](http://bbs.themex.net/showthread.php?t=16852265). However, this font is ***simplified Chinese only***, and we can imagine it will be even more difficult to read than `8x8` resolution characters, so my conclusion for OP's question is "about `8x8`".

## 12x12 would be moderate

The following paragraphs are rendered by the `方正像素12` font with its `12x12` resolution glyphs. Almost every character can be recognized without context. Of course, compared with the `16x16` resolution, it has to lose strokes even for many simplified characters; however, yes, native speakers may feel relaxed to read them now.

[image: 方正像素12]

Comment: Hey @Stan, do you happen to know where we could find the _Special SimSun_ font? Also, thank you for this great writeup — it's still useful after three years!

Comment: @rramphal try [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GMzc4jfLKk_1fKsi6Q_hlTKQ8ebH1JO2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: .@Stan thank you so much for taking the time to upload it! Unfortunately, when I loaded it, it loaded as Sim Sun regular. Do you mind double-checking? 

Comment: @rramphal SimSun-special.ttf SHA1 = `079ac3d82f5bad960296ead8ae714b347ff3ea85`. It seemed the font maker didn't fill up all the properties carefully: **PostScript name** missing, **Full name** corrupt `®™°•?`; **Family** OK `SimSun`, but **Style** `regular` (notice it's not `Regular` as the original SimSun). And finally the font's **Unique name** is `特制宋体`. You may check the details by using a proper font viewer, e.g. Font Book on macOS.

Comment: Is there a URI that works in 2021 for the typeface that works for 8x8?

Comment: Any place to find the font right now?

Comment: Where can the `7x7` resolution font `超宋体` (**Super Song**) be found? The download links [[1](http://www.namipan.com/d/%5b简体%5d超宋体.7z/f3afce5ad2260b20ceb320e8efd61e8192258bf0cb1a6100), [2](http://www.namipan.com/d/BDF.7z/6a7d8e7869e4cd48fa806f1bcc4cb2b249dbe042e6173902), [3](http://www.damipan.com/file/1kjg1YB.html)] in the [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160623185716/http://bbs.themex.net/showthread.php?t=16852265) of the link above don't work.

Comment: @AlexanderZ. Thank you for the bounty on [the search](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54703/)! Is your bounty meant to push the search for the font 超宋体 or 明兰终 or both? I wanted to split that question into two questoins (one for each font) because the two discussions are separate and growing, but I don't want to interfere with your bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Stan's answers are great, but assume **NATIVE speakers**.  As a newbie, and assuming  **GRAYSCALE** (I personally find it hard to read anything lower than 16x16)...  If you are using an OLED display that is only capable of **monochrome**, I think newbies will need MUCH higher (at least 24x24).

Comment: I've just run into trying to show Chinese on an OLED (1-bit; on/off) display also. See [Drawing multilingual text using PIL and saving as 1-bit and 8-bit bitmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47545359/3904031).

Answer (score 1):

## Fonts designed with 7×7 characters

Note that in some font names and bitmap strike sizes below, "8 pixels" refers to **7 pixels character size plus 1 pixel spacing** between characters, whereas [the highest-voted answer above](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/16669/lowest-pixel-resolution-needed-to-support-chinese/16675#16675) refers to a larger character size of 8 pixels.

The following fonts have 7×7 Chinese characters:

- The font 超宋体. **Please help me find it** - see [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54703/downloading-low-resolution-chinese-fonts-7-pixels-high).
- The font 明兰终. **Please help me find it** - see [this question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54703/downloading-low-resolution-chinese-fonts-7-pixels-high).
- The fonts [明兰_UI, 明兰_Mono_TC, and other fonts with similar names](http://www.xz7.com/downinfo/298122.html). I don't know (see [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54703/downloading-low-resolution-chinese-fonts-7-pixels-high/54758?noredirect=1#comment73851_54758)) whether the 7×7 characters there are the same as in the font 明兰终.
- The font [DinkieBitmap](https://3type.cn/fonts/dinkie_bitmap/index.html). It supports various writing systems in addition to Chinese.
- The font [Chill-Bitmap](https://github.com/Warren2060/Chill-Bitmap).
- The font [BoutiqueBitmap7x7](https://github.com/scott0107000/BoutiqueBitmap7x7). Its early version was used to create the font Chill-Bitmap.
- A font that is included in the fonts XiaoDianZhen and ZFull-GB, as mentioned [here](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/142419693).
- The font Zfull-BIG5.
- The font [观致8px](https://www.maoken.com/freefonts/11358.html). It was used to create the font BoutiqueBitmap7x7 version 1.5 and a little bit to create the font Chill-Bitmap.
- The font [美咲フォント](https://littlelimit.net/misaki.htm). It (or early ones of [its versions](https://littlelimit.net/misaki.htm#history)) was used to create BoutiqueBitmap7x7, 观致8px, and Chill-Bitmap.

Comparison of 观致8px, BoutiqueBitmap7x7, 美咲ゴシック (one of [the variants of 美咲フォント](https://littlelimit.net/misaki.htm#sample)), and Chill-Bitmap:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on commercial applications, the smallest size character for simplified or traditional Chinese bitmap font is 11x12 (W x H) pixels. Anything smaller than that will give you problems and result in customer complaint. On the other hand, if you are doing something non-commercial in nature, you can try smaller sizes of bitmap fonts at your own risk. To get info on high quality bitmap fonts for commercial applications, go to http://www.bitmapfonts.com

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 fonts that support Chinese.

First is the closed-source font: [Dinkie Bitmap (丁卯点阵体)](https://3type.cn/fonts/dinkie_bitmap/index.html). It has a set of ~7300 characters and support multi language.
The second is open-source: [Chill Bitmap (寒蝉点阵体)](https://github.com/Warren2060/Chill-Bitmap). It has ~13600 chars, but I don't know there are many chars stolen from Dinkie or not.

Comment: But that is not at all what the question is asking about.