# Traces of the Chinese font "明兰终" (7×7 pixel characters)

Tags: simplified-characters, software, fonts

[This page](https://github.com/R32/heaps/wiki/Displaying-Text) mentions a Chinese font named 明兰终, which is designed with Chinese characters sized 7×7 pixels:

> "明兰终"，估计只有 7*7 字体估计是作者自已点出来的
>
> > 详细说明在, http://bbs.themex.net/forumdisplay.php?f=87 字体可以百度到下载。 使用 fontBuild 工具虽然选择的字号都是一样的，但出来的字比 Hippopo 小一号

(Edit: The last sentence might refer to the fact that "8 pixels" in some cases refers to 7 pixels character size plus 1 pixel spacing between characters, and in other cases to a larger character size of 8 pixels, like the character size of the Hippopo font. Does that make sense?)

I found a file named `「明兰·终」.ttf` [here](https://apk.tw/thread-783214-1-1.html), but after logging in and trying to download it,
I'm getting an **error message that I don't understand**: "抱歉，本版塊下載附件 碎鑽-1，本操作後您的碎鑽將不足 0 個，無法下載。[您可以點我進入了解《下載證書》勳章免碎鑽下載的方法。](https://apk.tw/thread-807190-1-1.html)"

[This page](https://www.ccc5.cc/1156.html) seems to indicate a connection between `明兰·终` and `明兰_Mono` (post title `明兰MONO`, below it says `Name=明兰·终`, under `[FontSubstitutes]` there's `XHei=明兰_Mono`, `XHei Mono=明兰_Mono` and so on, post tag `明兰`). But `明兰_mono.ttf` from [here](http://houyuaner.weebly.com/fonts.html) doesn't contain bitmaps.

Are there some traces of the font "明兰终"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is traditional Chinese:

```
抱歉，本版塊下載附件 碎鑽-1，本操作後您的碎鑽將不足 0 個，無法下載
```

translate to Simplified Chinese:

```
抱歉，本版块下载附件 碎钻-1，本操作后您的碎钻将不足 0 个，无法下载。
```

translate to English:

```
Sorry, downloading attachments in this section deducts 1 Fragmented Diamond. After this operation, you will have less than 0 Fragmented Diamonds, so you won't be able to download it.
```

Now I have downloaded it from [the link](https://apk.tw/thread-783214-1-1.html) as you mentioned, see below picture:

[image]

But how I send to you?

See link at https://filetransfer.io/data-package/AuL496dW#link

click above link will see below picture:

[image]

### Update

I new add a file upload it at https://filetransfer.io/data-package/o2xYqLRF#link

The file that I download at http://www.xz7.com/downinfo/298122.html

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. This helps with the search. How did you get the "Fragmented Diamond"? This file contains several fonts, but none of them contains [bitmaps](https://fontforge.org/docs/tutorial/editexample8.html) nor has a pixelated look. I also doubt that the 7*7 pixel size was achieved through [font hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting). Is it likely that the name 明兰终 (due to being a straightforward pun or something) was given to two different font files?

Comment: Or maybe I misunderstood the quote "明兰终"，估计只有 7*7 字体估计是作者自已点出来的 - maybe someone took the font collection named 明兰终 and added 7*7 bitmaps without renaming the file, so now there are several different files named 明兰终?

Comment: @root The original file (size 8.35MB) that I upload named `apk.tw_「明兰·终」.ttf` ,  but when I upload it, it auto let file name change `apk.tw_「明兰·终」.ttf` to `apk.tw_*.ttf`.  Is the file I downloaded correct?

Comment: Changing the file name isn't a problem. The file size 8.35MB is in accordance with the info on [the webpage](https://apk.tw/thread-783214-1-1.html). Maybe that webpage has a different file with the same file name than the 7*7 font descriped on [this other webpage](https://github.com/R32/heaps/wiki/Displaying-Text). Is it likely that two different people decided to name their file 明兰终 because that name is somehow "normal"/straightforward?

Comment: @root Can you list your question separately in your original question(or in Chinese)?

Comment: I've now posted it as a separate question [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54760/meaning-of-font-description-%e6%98%8e%e5%85%b0%e7%bb%88-%e4%bc%b0%e8%ae%a1%e5%8f%aa%e6%9c%89-77-%e5%ad%97%e4%bd%93%e4%bc%b0%e8%ae%a1%e6%98%af%e4%bd%9c%e8%80%85%e8%87%aa%e5%b7%b2%e7%82%b9%e5%87%ba%e6%9d%a5%e7%9a%84).

Comment: @root try this link http://www.xz7.com/downinfo/298122.html

Comment: Perfect, the fonts 明兰_UI, 明兰_Mono_TC, etc. from [here](http://www.xz7.com/downinfo/298122.html) have bitmaps with 7×7 Chinese characters, thank you! Maybe they are the same font as 明兰终. I'm not sure how to interpret "终" in "明兰终".

Comment: @root It's not important that `how to interpret "终" in "明兰终"`,  what can be said is a little practical significance, without paying attention to it. If my answer solves your problem, please accept it and vote up it.

Comment: Thank you! I had upvoted your answer, and I was waiting for the bounty to end before accepting your answer (because my question was broad when the bounty was placed, so I wasn't sure whether the bounty guy wanted more answers). Congratulations on winning the +100 bounty and thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @root I just note that you modify your question, are you looking for the  明兰终 font?

Comment: Yes, I made the question less broad and more in line with the answer, so that they match each other nicely. Yes, I'm still looking for the 7×7 pixels characters from the 明兰终 font, but with lower priority now that you kindly showed me the fonts 明兰_UI, 明兰_Mono_TC, and so on. I'm not sure whether their 7×7 pixels characters are the same as in the 明兰终 font. "终" in "明兰终" doesn't make that clear, as far as I understood. I'm also planning a separate question about the 超宋体 font.

Comment: @root  I don't understand fonts, but it seems that 明兰终 is just the name of a font and the character "终" doesn't have any specific meaning in this context.