# Meaning of font description: "明兰终"，估计只有 7*7 字体估计是作者自已点出来的

Tags: translation, fonts

[This webpage](https://github.com/R32/heaps/wiki/Displaying-Text) mentions a font named 明兰终 with Chinese characters that have a size of **7×7 pixels**:

> "明兰终"，估计只有 7*7 字体估计是作者自已点出来的

What does this Chinese sentence mean?

Might 作者 refer to the author of the webpage or of the font? Might that be the same person?

Did a font named "明兰终" exist before the `7*7` topic came up? Were `7*7` [bitmaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts) added (drawing bitmaps requires clicking - is this what 点出来的 refers to?) to that font, possibly without renaming it? Or does 点出来的 refer to the author of the webpage selecting that font - maybe the font "明兰终" without dedicated `7*7` bitmaps is simply being rendered to a `7*7` resolution?

Does the author of the webpage think that this font is the only one (只有) with `7*7` character size?

What are the two things that the author of the webpage is unsure about (估计 is written twice)?

[This forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20170326235101/http://bbs.themex.net/forumdisplay.php?f=87) is referred to for further info (which we haven't searched yet).

A search for this font is ongoing [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/54703/downloading-low-resolution-chinese-fonts-7-pixels-high). A font named 明兰·终 *without* `7*7` characters has been found. Is it likely that several different font files (one with and one without `7*7` characters) were named 明兰终 because that's in some way a "normal"/straightforward name for a font?

Comment: Don't really know anything about fonts. I use Libre Office Writer. It seems all the Chinese fonts I have can go down to 6pt, which is the smallest option I have. 96 appears to be the largest option. As far as I know a font is like a vector drawing, can be scaled up or down. However, in gimp I can scale a text right down to 0 pixel! Might be hard to read in that case!

Comment: @Pedroski pt (points) and pixels are different units. Only a very small percentage of fonts produces legible Chinese characters sized 7×7 pixels, see [here](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/54761/36286). Such fonts are specially designed for that. My question is what the following sentence means: "明兰终"，估计只有 7*7 字体估计是作者自已点出来的

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "明兰终"，估计只有 7*7 字体估计是作者自已点出来的

can change to

> "`明兰终`字体"，估计只有7*7像素(pixel), 这个`明兰终`字体估计是作者自已点出来的

means the  font named 明兰终 that is the only one (只有) with 7×7 pixels, because drawing bitmaps requires clicking, so the font was created by the author by `clicking`(估计是**作者**自已点出来的).

The term "**作者**" here refers solely to the creator of the font(明兰终).

Comment: The author of the webpage or of the font? Might that be the same person?

Comment: @root The author of the font(The most likely scenario is that the author refers to the font). The author of webpage seems that only mention the font(明兰终). There are not the same person, They are two different individuals. Their relationship is more akin to `a paper author(here is the author of the webpage)` needing to clarify something and directly quoting a conclusion found by `someone  else(here is the author of font)`. The term "作者" here refers solely to the creator of the font(明兰终).